# Authentication to Apache Drill is temporary failing

Tags: mapr, pydrill

I'm running a 5 Nodes Mapr Drill cluster, and everything is working fine, except that sometimes (can be multiple time during the day, sometimes once in a few days, no specific pattern), when I try to connect to one of the drillbits (Via Drill Web-UI / PyDrill), the login is failing with Invalid username/password error, even though the password and username are correct!
Scripts that trying to open connections with PyDrill also failing with the same error.

1. The issue is resolved by itself after a while, or when I restart the affected drillbit with maprcli command.
2. this issue occurs only on specifc drillbits and not on all. (Usually node #1. It happens on others too, but only a few times. On the first node it happens almost on a daily basis)
3. Login is failing with all users. Mapr user, AD users, etc.

Did anyone encounter this? I'm trying to find the root cause and a solution. I suspect it is happening when the cluster is running on low memory so the login service (PAM) is failing.

Thanks!